# How to return elements of an array with the highest values?

Tags: php

In my code I have two elements which has the same age `"Joe"=>"43"` and `"Rob"=>"43"` .

My code output is:

> Joe

I want to output:

> Joe and Rob

Because they has the highest value.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $cur = 1;

    $age = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "37", "Joe" => "43", "Rob" => "43");
    $new_array = array();
    arsort($age);
    $new_array = $age;
    $key = array_search(max($new_array), $new_array);

    while ($cur > 0) {
        echo $key;
        $cur--;
    }
?>
```

Comment: just to clear things up for you and avoid confusion. you have a multidimensional array of associative arrays. An object would be something like a class.

Comment: Thank for tha @iam-decoder

Comment: You should not add the interget values as string, but as integer: `array("Peter" => 35)`. Integers are faster than strings, use them where you can :)

Comment: Ok . I will take note of that @Martijn . Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd change the keys and values in the array, then sort by key and return the values of the first key:

```
$ages = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "37", "Joe" => "43", "Rob" => "43");
$new = array();

foreach ($ages as $name => $age) {
  $new[$age][] = $name;
}

uksort($new, function($ka, $kb) { return $kb - $ka; }); // or just krsort($new);
$new = array_values($new)[0]; // <- to use this you have to have at least PHP 5.4

// if you have PHP < 5.4 you can simply do it in two steps:
// $new = array_values($new);
// $new = $new[0];
```

[See it in action!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7b0a46170b990107a77efdbda9605648c4a6e74)

EDIT: [even simpler!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f463c39c80799bc238f4284785f46a4dec51d8f8)

```
$ages = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "37", "Joe" => "43", "Rob" => "43");
$max = max($ages);
$new = array_keys(array_filter($ages, function ($age) use ($max) { return $age == $max; }));
```

Comment: your answer is fine the way it is. the only concern I can think is that they'd have to be using php 5.4+ to get this script to work with the immediate array access of a returned value on the last line :)

Comment: @iam-decoder you're right, I added a note about it!

Comment: Why don't you use `ksort` instead of `uksort`?

Comment: This is a bad solution because you walk the array three times. It can be solved in only one iteration

Comment: @Miguel I would favor cleanliness over performance in such simple use case.

Comment: Always is important, especially if you can solve your code in few lines. That impacts in the scalability of your application and make it more maintainable and readable because it is simplest

Comment: @Miguel As far as scalability this answer is much less scalable than the answer of svnm, which can run in linear time complexity.

Comment: @Tim both my solution (second one) and svnm are `O(n)`, which should be all it matters.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Actually it uses the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm under the hood and 'takes O(n log n) comparisons to sort n items. In the worst case, it makes O(n2) comparisons, though this behavior is rare.'

Comment: @Tim I didn't know that! Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain? I'd like to improve my answer if I can!

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
$people = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "37", "Joe" => "43", "Rob" => "43");
$max = max($people);
$result = array_filter($people, function($age) use ($max){ return $max == $age; });
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [Joe] => 43
    [Rob] => 43
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check it manually:

```
$age = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "37", "Joe" => "43", "Rob" => "43");
$new_array = array();
arsort($age);
$new_array = $age;
$max = max($new_array);

$results = array();
foreach ($new_array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == $max) {
        $results[] = $key;
    }
}

echo implode(' and ', $results);
// will output "joe and bob"
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer of @matteo-tassinari and @evilive much more and wanted to propose it myself. But since the question of efficency came up, here is a solution using only one loop and therefore has a linear time complexity:

```
<?php
$max = ~PHP_INT_MAX;
$result = [];
foreach($age as $key => $value) {
    if($value > $max) {
        $result = [ $key => $value ];
        $max = $value;
    }
    if($value == $max) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

And there exists another solution, that uses [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort):

```
function bucket($ages) {
    $buckets = [];
    foreach($ages as $key => $value) {
      $buckets[$value][] = $key;
    }
    return $buckets[max(array_keys($buckets))];
}
```

Regarding the discusson about peformance and scalability, I wrote a small benchmark script for four kinds of proposed solutions (loop, [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625037/3507477), [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625017/3507477), bucket):

```
<?php
function loop($ages) {
    $max = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach($ages as $key => $value) {
            if($value > $max) {
                    $result = [ $key => $value ];
                    $max = $value;
            }
            if($value == $max) {
                    $result[$key] = $value;
            }
    }
    return array_keys($result);
}

function filter($ages) {
    $max = max($ages);
    $new = array_filter($ages, function ($age) use ($max) { return $age == $max; });
    return array_keys($new);
}

function bucket($ages) {
    $buckets = [];
    foreach($ages as $key => $value) {
            $buckets[$value][] = $key;
    }
    return $buckets[max(array_keys($buckets))];
}


for($n = 2; $n < 10000000; $n*=2) {

    $ages = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $ages['name_'.$i] = rand(0,100);
    }

    $start = microtime(true);
    echo $n.';';
    loop($ages);
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).';';
    $start = microtime(true);
    arsort($ages);
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).';';
    $start = microtime(true);
    filter($ages);
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).';';
    bucket($ages);
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).';';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Limited Live Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ca6e8231c1eba409564343c8863382eebaa9279)

Please double-check if this is right: Using php-5.6.15 on the command line, my timings look something like this:

```
elements;loop;sort;filter;bucket
...
4096;0.001507;0.009868;0.01211;0.01453;
8192;0.003704;0.002483;0.02488;0.03035;
16384;0.006660;0.01010;0.05396;0.06723;
32768;0.01417;0.01271;0.09163;0.1163;
...
1048576;0.4227;0.9791;2.983;3.943;
2097152;0.8572;2.320;6.064;8.020;
4194304;1.787;4.981;11.90;16.04;
8388608;3.892;10.84;24.76;33.31;
```

For small number of elements, the difference between the methods is not really big, but as you can see, for the largest value the `loop` method is two times faster than `sort`, 8 times faster than `filter` and eleven times faster than `bucket`. So if your array is *huge*, you should use `loop`.

Comment: This is the best answer by my opinion, it runs in linear time complexity.

Comment: My solution using `max()` and `array_filter()` should still be `O(n)`, so computationally equivalent to this one, isn't it?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Computational complexity is not the same as performance. If an algorithm runs in O(n^2) for 100 items with each step taking 1ms that is 10 seconds. If it runs in O(n) for 100 items with each step taking 1 second that's 100 seconds. Which algorithm is better?

Comment: The order of an algorithm is an important thing to know as it tells you useful things about how it scales with performance, but it's not the only thing or sometimes even the most important thing to know.

Comment: @TimB yes I understand what you mean, but the other user Tim said about "linear time complexity", and in this aspect, both our answers have such property

Comment: Yours was linear (2*O(N) and his is linear (O(N)) but some of the other suggestions were O(N^2). I expect he was talking about those answers.

Comment: @TimB and Matteo Tassinari: I indeed was talking about the first solution of Matteo. However this is still a superior answer, by my knowledge, as it avoids unnecessary additional loops. But it does scale as well as the second answer of Matteo.

Comment: @svrnm I appreciate your effort for the benchmark script. Maybe it is a good idea to expand it so that it becomes visible what scales and what does not scale, since the question of performance began with a discussion about scalability. :)

Comment: @Tim: I added some more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array methods **[next](http://php.net/manual/es/function.next.php)** and **[key](http://php.net/manual/es/function.key.php)**.

With **next()** you will move the array pointer one position. With **key()** you will get the key of the element of the array pointer. So the final code will be something like this:

```
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43","Rob"=>"43");
arsort($age);
echo key($age);

next($age);
echo key($age);
```

[Check it working here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12266e98731df1708023c82eeabe93a8a9472553).

Comment: No, this is not the most efficient solution, since sorting has a complexity of `O(n*log n)`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this

```
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43","Rob"=>"43");

$max = max($age); //get the highest age

foreach ($age as $key => $value) { //iterate through $age array
    if ($value == $max) {          //if the value is equal to max age 
        echo $key."<br />";        // then echo the key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why no one is using built in solution:

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43","Rob"=>"43");
$new = array_keys($age, max($age));
```

returns
array('Joe', 'Rob')

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php says:

> array_keys ( array $array , mixed $search_value [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : array
>
> If a search_value is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are returned.