# How can I find array from multiple array based on highest amount in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am facing some issue in multiple array to find height amount array.

I want to get the array that have high amount from multiple array to one new array in PHP.

If two or more arrays have same highest amount than get any array as new array.

Currently, I have two arrays having same amount but its not highest value so it will not select in the sample data.

The Output Array should be combined with the highest amount with its code and type.

---

### Input:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => Custom discount
            [amount] => 3514.55
            [type] => fixed_amount
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => MerOrder300
            [amount] => 400.00
            [type] => fixed_amount
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => MerOrder400
            [amount] => 400.00
            [type] => fixed_amount
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [code] => MerOrder450
            [amount] => 450.00
            [type] => fixed_amount
        )

)
```

---

### Output:

```
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => Custom discount
            [amount] => 3514.55
            [type] => fixed_amount
        )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You haven't posted any code, so we can't help you find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column` with `array_keys` and `max`

```
$amountArr = array_column($arr, null, 'amount');
print_r($amountArr[max(array_keys($amountArr))]);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/d2WRf

Answer (score 1):

Rakesh's solution eliminates the possibility of multiple qualifying subarrays by using `amount` as new keys during the `array_column()` call.

There are at least a handful of different ways to perform this task.  Here is just one -- extract the max value, then filter the whole array using that value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/I5UOQ))

```
$array = [
    [
        'code' => 'Custom discount',
        'amount' => 3514.55,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder300',
        'amount' => 400.00,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder400',
        'amount' => 3514.55,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder450',
        'amount' => 450.00,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ]
];

$max = max(
    array_column($array, 'amount')
);
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($subarray) use ($max) {
            return $subarray['amount'] == $max;
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Linear / Highest performing techniques like linauror's answer can be explained in this similar pre-existing page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33624879/2943403

Comment: What do you mean by _"If two or more arrays have same highest amount than get any array as new array."_? @Muneeb that English is not perfectly clear.  If two subarrays contain the highest value, do you expect 1 or 2 subarrays in the result?  Your sample input does not reflect your desire because only one subarray contains the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach`:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'code' => 'Custom discount', 
        'amount' => 3514.55,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder300', 
        'amount' => 400.00,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],    
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder400', 
        'amount' => 400.00,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'MerOrder450', 
        'amount' => 450.00,
        'type' => 'fixed_amount'
    ]
];

$max = $arr[0];

foreach ($arr as $line) {
    if ($line['amount'] > $max['amount']) {
        $max = $line;
    }
}

print_r($max);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.