# Get the most repeated elements inside array, if more than one is the most repeated, get results alphabatically in order PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's suppose I have a fruit array, I want to know which one or which ones are the most repeated, for example:

```
$array = array('apple','banana','apple','orange','grape','orange', 'mango');
    
//Here I get an associative array with each fruit name as key and number of times repeated as value:    
$values = array_count_values($array);

//Here I order the array descendently in order to get the most repeated values first: 
arsort($values);
```

As you can see, apple and orange are repeated the same amount of times, how could I get these values in a dymanic way in which I always get `n` fruit names that are the most repeated?

After I get this, I need to sort those most repeated values alphabetically, which I think I could use the `ksort();` function when I have those most repeated values in an array, so for example if I have:

```
[orange] => 2
[apple] => 2
[grape] => 2
```

The result should be:

```
[apple] => 2
[grape] => 2
[orange] => 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by `n fruit names that are the most repeated`? Limit the amount of fruits displayed?

Comment: @Michel What I meant was that, I could easily grab the first element of the array after using arsort(), but, what if there is more than one fruit that is repeated the most?, like in the last example I gave.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return elements of an array with the highest values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624879/how-to-return-elements-of-an-array-with-the-highest-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625292/1685196), this will do:

```
$array = array('orange','apple','banana','apple','orange','grape','orange', 'mango','apple');

$values = array_count_values($array);

$max = max($values);

$fruits = array_filter($values, function($num) use ($max){ return $max == $num; });

$ksort($fruits);
```

Output:

```
[
apple => 3,
orange => 3
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Online PHP evaluator](https://3v4l.org/F0upI)

Use `array_count_values()` and count all the values of the array, then run through foreach() to map a new array, run `asort()` and maintain index association then run `arsort()` to reverse the order...

```php
$array = array('apple','banana','apple','orange','grape','orange', 'mango');

$fruits = array_count_values($array);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {         
    $arr[$key] = $val;
}
asort($arr);
arsort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

OUTPUT For: `$array = array('apple','banana','apple','orange','grape','orange', 'mango');`

```
array(5) {
  ["apple"] => int(2)
  ["orange"] => int(2)
  ["banana"] => int(1)
  ["grape"] => int(1)
  ["mango"] => int(1)
}
```

OUTPUT For: `$array = array('watermelon', 'plum', 'apple', 'watermelon', 'banana','plum', 'apple','plum', 'orange','grape','orange', 'mango', 'watermelon');`

```
array(7) {
  ["plum"]=>
  int(3)
  ["watermelon"]=>
  int(3)
  ["apple"]=>
  int(2)
  ["orange"]=>
  int(2)
  ["banana"]=>
  int(1)
  ["grape"]=>
  int(1)
  ["mango"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

[Different fruit list](https://3v4l.org/fM7jl)